# how to add field to proto schema at runtime?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, prototype, proto

is there any way that i can add new field to a protobuf message during the runtime?

I can successfully create new protobuf type using FileDescriptorProto, but is there any way that i can add new field to existing protobuf type?

Comment: What are you trying to do? How would the sender and receiver both understand the modified schema?

Comment: You could always use `Descriptor::CopyTo()` to populate a `DescriptorProto`, to which you can append your additional fields and put in a `FileDescriptorProto`. But as @AlanBirtles says, this sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: the sender and receiver can read the same config, so i do not need to compile both the sender and receiver to get new proto online. ps: I can use reflection to update the newly updated field.